# <svg> & <img> show different glyphs; <svg> has artifact

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

In React, I'm trying to display an SVG & be able to dynamically change it's color, but there is a weird "artifacting" going on when used as an  component, even with the exact same code.

**Left** is `<img src="checkmark.svg"/>`, **Right** is as an `<svg>` React component

[image]

Code:

**checkmark.svg**

```xml
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M9 24L13.5 28.5L31 11" stroke="#626262" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

**CheckmarkSVG.jsx**

```
const StepCheckmarkSVG = () => {
    return (
        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M9 24L13.5 28.5L31 11" stroke="#626262" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

It's literally the same SVG code. Why are they displaying differently?

Comment: You must have a CSS `fill` rule applied on the <path>, it can be inherited from the `svg` and will anyway have more importance than your `fill="none"` attribute. Simply open your Dev-tools, search for the path, check the applied styles and fix the rule that leaked on it (you can also force `style="fill:none"` on the <path>, but better fix the leaking one)

Comment: @Kaiido it was this. So simple. ‍♂️
Post your comment as an answer so I can mark it!

Comment: I consider your question to be off-topic, for two border-line reasons: 1. It lacks a [mcve], given the situation I could guess the issue confidently, but still, questions seeking debugging help must have a minimal repro. Then, this question is very unlikely to be found by anyone facing the same issue in the future. So I did comment and vote to close your question, and I'd prefer see you delete it rather than me answering it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks good to me:

```js
const element = 
  <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M9 24L13.5 28.5L31 11" stroke="#626262" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
  </svg>;

ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you can't reproduce the artefact, perhaps it's a CSS issue applying a fill or stroke to the underlying SVG markup?